# Is there a better way of replacing last string after a space with another string if some conditions met?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace the last string after a space with another string only if the last string is included within the string I intend to replace it with or just want to merge them together.(Did I just massacre English language)

```
      let before = this.text.split(' ')
      let a = before.slice(before.length-1)
      if (response.data.text[0].includes(a)) {
        this.preResult.push(before.slice(0, before.length-1).replace(',', ' ') + ' ' + response.data.text[0])
      } else 
      this.preResult.push(this.text + ' ' + response.data.text[0])

    })
```

`jaguar lion tiger panda`

and the string that I might replace the last one is pandas Expected result is:

`jaguar lion tiger pandas`

if the string were cat Expected result:

`jaguar lion tiger panda cat`

Comment: Your example is not clear.

Comment: And could add a working snippet?

Comment: this code didnt work btw

Answer (score 1):

You could [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on a space and then use  [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the longer or shorter version is part of the last word:

```js
let str = "jaguar lion tiger panda";

const strings = [
  "pan",
  "pandas",
  "test"
];

strings.forEach(s => {
  let parts = str.split(' ');
  let last = parts[parts.length - 1];

  if (s.includes(last) || last.includes(s)) {
    parts[parts.length - 1] = s;
  } else {
    parts.push(s)
  }

  console.log(parts.join(' '));
});
```

You could shorten the `if` `else` part to use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) if you prefer:

```
s.includes(last) || last.includes(s) ? parts[parts.length - 1] = s : parts.push(s);
```